# Efficient way to summarise, re-group and plot data set of group frequencies in R

Tags: r, histogram, ggplot2

I have a set of data for three groups (A, B, C) which gives information on how often a certain value "x" (between -3 and +3) is observed for that group (0 to 100). To give a **simplified** example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 1),
                 A = c(0, 10, 25, 30, 15, 0, 0),
                 B = c(25, 30, 24, 29, 2, 15, 0),
                 C = c(0, 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 30))
```

The actual data set is quite big, however, so there is a large number of very detailed x values (at least two decimals) for which each group has associated frequencies, which often drop to near-zero for certain x values. When plotting this using the command below, the result looks rather convoluted.

```
df <- melt(df, id = "x")
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

1. What would be the best way to calculate summary statistics for each
   group? (mean, median, ...)
2. What would be the most effective way to aggregate x values and their
   neighbours into ranges of x values, summing up the associated group
   frequencies in the process, to get a more generalised picture?
3. How would one tell ggplot to produce a histogram or density plot which
   accounts for the observed frequencies, so that one would [get
   a plot which looks like this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_%28ggplot2%29/#histogram-and-density-plots-with-multiple-groups)?

I thought of iterating over the data set and doing all of the above "manually", but figured that this would be inefficient and prone to errors. Any suggestions you may have would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a histogram you need to remove the "value" variable and create the corresponding number of rows for "x" based on that value. So, if for group A you have x = 3 and value = 10, the process has to create x = 3 for group A 10 times. Run the process step by step to see how it works. I've included decimals for "x".

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(22)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.01),
                 A = round(c(rnorm(200, 30,3),rnorm(401,20,4))),
                 B = round(c(rexp(300, 1/5), rexp(301,1/20))),
                 C = round(runif(601, 2, 25)))

df <- melt(df, id = "x")


# create number of rows for each x and group based on the value
df2=
    df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(x = rep(.$x, .$value),
                variable = rep(.$variable, .$value))) %>%
  ungroup


# check mean and median x values for each group
df2 %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(),
            MEAN_X= mean(x),
            MEDIAN_X= median(x))

#   variable     N      MEAN_X MEDIAN_X
# 1        A 13979 -0.27480292    -0.47
# 2        B  7051  0.84527159     1.03
# 3        C  7906 -0.03190741    -0.07



ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, fill=variable)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.2, alpha=.5, position="dodge")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_density()
```

[image]

If you want to group x for each group in terms of the frequencies you can use a regression tree method that will split x into bins and will give you the break-point(s):

```
library(party)

# tree for group A only
model = ctree(value~x+variable, data = df[df$variable=="A",])

plot(model, type = "simple")
```

[image]

This tells you that for group A there's a break point at x = -1.01 (you can visualise from the histograms as well) which splits x in two groups. The left side averages a value = 29.8 and the right side averages a value = 19.99. The number of observations in each bin are 200 and 401 respectively. Which sounds correct, as I've created this variable like that in the beginning.

Note that the trees are statistical models, which split your variable(s) based on statistical significant differences (or other metrics). You can't force any grouping by yourself. If you want to do that it's better to group your variable "x" in N groups (based on quantiles maybe? or something else that makes more sense to you) and see how the value changes within those groups.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @AntoniosK. My goal for (1) was to obtain the "x" values corresponding to the mean/median for each group, in order to get a sense which group lies more towards the left, which is more towards the right. Regarding (2) and (3), the idea is to re-group the data into "bins" in order to get a rougher picture of their relative distributions. My hope was that doing so would produce a data set where very high "value" values are less attenuated. Plotting this using ggplot, the end result was then supposed to look like the histogram/density plot examples. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I missed the point where you say that x can have decimal points. I used your example and the x values were discrete and some (reasonable) ideas didn't seem right. I'll try to update and include some more info.

Comment: Thank you, AntoniosK, and apologies again for my late reply! Your approach works perfectly on the data set I've been using, and so I will mark this as the accepted answer. I've recently been given an updated data set, however, where the values for A, B, C can now also contain decimals. Could your approach also be adapted to work in such cases? (Apologies for the imposition, I realise you have already put a lot of work into this)

Comment: If you want to continue with that histogram and density approach the easiest way is to round those values (A,B,C), first, and then apply exactly the same method. This is needed only for the plots as they use `df2`. The tree approach uses `df` so it will be able to handle decimal points. Create some simple examples yourself and see how the results look like.

Comment: If you want to use the decimal values without rounding, you can use your `df` dataset and do : `ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=value, color=variable))+
  geom_line()` and `ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=value, color=variable))+
  stat_smooth()`. The 1st one will give you something like the one you posted initially and the 2nd one will give you a smoothed version of that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I followed the latter approach and also calculated the mean manually using the formula for the weighted arithmetic mean.